# Clickable span not calling javascript even though w3school example works

Tags: javascript, html

I have a clickable span element that is supposed to call a javascript function that toggles a dropdown. This is an amalgum of two w3schools examples linked here.

[onclick with span element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_color)

[clickable dropdowns with w3.css](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_dropdown_click)

My code is below, the HTML and JS are inline in the same HTML document. The CSS can be ignored, it is just renamed w3.css stuff (w3- to mxa-).

HTML

```
    <div class="mxa-dropdown-click">
        <span onclick="menu_click("page-menu")">
            <span class="mxa-xlarge">&#9776;</span>
        </span>
        <div id="page-menu" 
            class="mxa-dropdown-content mxa-bar-block mxa-border" 

            >

                <a href="/entity/show/42" class="mxa-bar-item">
                    Show Entity
                </a>

                <a href="/record/add/prompt/42" class="mxa-bar-item">
                    Add Record
                </a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    function menu_click(menu_id) {
        window.alert('i got to here');
        var menu = document.getElementById(menu_id);
        if (menu.className.indexOf("mxa-show") == -1) {
            menu.className += "mxa-show";
        } else { 
            menu.className = menu.className.replace("mxa-show", "");
        }
    }
```

I have edited an example from the w3schools site that to me looks essentially identical to my code but which does work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span id="demo" onclick="myFunction('demo')">Click me to change my text color.</span>

<script>
function myFunction(arg) {
    window.alert('i got to here');
  document.getElementById(arg).style.color = "blue";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I never 'get to here' in my code. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: alert will show go to here

Comment: You got error in this tag ``<span onclick="menu_click("page-menu")">``   Use instead  ``<span onclick="menu_click('page-menu')">``     Use Single quotes(') instead of double quotes(") for **page-menu**

Comment: Use single quotes like this onclick="menu_click('page-menu')".

Comment: Thanks all so much, I was too close to it and couldn't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forming the *onclick* attribute with invalid syntax, change the inner double quotes to single quotes.

Change

```
<span onclick="menu_click("page-menu")">
```

To

```
<span onclick="menu_click('page-menu')">
```

**OR:** With double quotes inside the single quotes

```
<span onclick='menu_click("page-menu")'>
```

```js
function menu_click(menu_id) {
  window.alert('i got to here');
  var menu = document.getElementById(menu_id);
  if (menu.className.indexOf("mxa-show") == -1) {
      menu.className += "mxa-show";
  } else { 
      menu.className = menu.className.replace("mxa-show", "");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mxa-dropdown-click">
  <span onclick="menu_click('page-menu')">
    <span class="mxa-xlarge">&#9776;</span>
  </span>
  <div id="page-menu" 
      class="mxa-dropdown-content mxa-bar-block mxa-border">
    <a href="/entity/show/42" class="mxa-bar-item">
        Show Entity
    </a>
    <a href="/record/add/prompt/42" class="mxa-bar-item">
        Add Record
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All are same except onclick `quote` .check your quotes on onclick call

```
onclick="menu_click('page-menu')"
```

```js
function menu_click(menu_id) {
  window.alert('i got to here');
  var menu = document.getElementById(menu_id);
  if (menu.className.indexOf("mxa-show") == -1) {
    menu.className += "mxa-show";
  } else {
    menu.className = menu.className.replace("mxa-show", "");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mxa-dropdown-click">
  <span onclick="menu_click('page-menu')">
            <span class="mxa-xlarge">&#9776;</span>
  </span>
  <div id="page-menu" class="mxa-dropdown-content mxa-bar-block mxa-border">

    <a href="/entity/show/42" class="mxa-bar-item">
                    Show Entity
                </a>

    <a href="/record/add/prompt/42" class="mxa-bar-item">
                    Add Record
                </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are calling function error. Just replace these line of code. 
Hope it will help you.

```
<span onclick="menu_click('page-menu')">
   <span class="mxa-xlarge">&#9776;</span>
</span>
```